# Switch user sends me to the lock screen - what do I need to do to make this work?

Tags: 10.10

When I select switch user from the user menu, it drops me into the lock screen for the current user, not the login screen for the new user. It used to work for me on other hardware with 9.04.

What do I need to do to make this work, or is it a possible bug?

This is an Acer Aspire One 751h with the cursed Intel GMA500 chipset. I'm running ppa's for X from the gma500 repository, with the basic Xorg.conf device section.

When I click on the change user button I get the lock screen again. I have two other test accounts which I've successfully logged in to, but never successfully switched to.

Comment: This happens when the system can't start another X server with the second (new) user - it disappears and goes back to your (locked) screen. Can you post up your graphics drivers' configuration and the hardware specs?

Answer (score 2):

Click on "Change User" on the lock dialog, and then on "Others...".

You should have another user available, obviously.